# Sitemap.XML for Sitecore JSS NextJS using SXA

Tags: nextjs, sxa-jss, sitemap

We are working on 10.2 Sitecore JSS (NextJS) using SXA. We have enabled Sitemap.xml in Sitecore using OOTB SXA settings. We can see sitemap item at this path `/sitecore/content/TenantName/Home/Settings/Sitemap`
The
`sitemap.xml` URL is working fine for the Sitecore domain (CM server), we can see all the desired URLs.

Our NextJS application is hosted on Vercel, but when we check the `sitemap.xml` URL in the Vercel domain, it gives a 404 error.

Does any specific thing need to be enabled to make sitemap.xml work for NextJS application hosted on Vercel?

Update:

- We are fetching layout data with the JSS REST Layout Service.
- Sitemap.xml is not working on localhost:3000 as well.

Comment: Check this blog post -> https://sitecore.hashnode.dev/building-sitemaps-using-sitecore-headless-services-nextjs-graphql

Comment: Another option for you: https://davegoosem.com/building-robots-txt-with-sitecore-jss-graphql/ - using the same concept

Answer (score 2):

If that works on local and not on Vercel, then I suspect its related to configuration (as you said). Here are details of how its implementation uses configuration and you can check those.

With SXA setup, you get a `sitemap-fetcher` plugin. It resides at path - `src\rendering\src\lib\sitemap-fetcher\plugins\graphql-sitemap-service.ts`

If you check its constructor -

```
constructor() {
this._graphqlSitemapService = new GraphQLSitemapService({
  endpoint: config.graphQLEndpoint,
  apiKey: config.sitecoreApiKey,
  siteName: config.jssAppName,
});
```

Assuming you are using GraphQl endpoint, you will need to share AppName if you have multisite setup in environment variables.

Second thing to look at is it's implementation,

```
async exec(context?: GetStaticPathsContext): Promise<StaticPath[]> {
    if (process.env.JSS_MODE === constants.JSS_MODE.DISCONNECTED) {
      return [];
    }
    return process.env.EXPORT_MODE
      ? this._graphqlSitemapService.fetchExportSitemap(config.defaultLanguage)
      : this._graphqlSitemapService.fetchSSGSitemap(context?.locales || []);
  }
```

If you have multilingual setup, you can check your default language (in `config.json`).

If this is all well then you can check if GraphQl query returns Sitemap.

EDIT 1 -
If you are using Experience Edge, you will need to store Sitemap in Media Item (This is recommended for Cloud version but no harm in trying).

[image]

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/configure-a-sitemap.html

And make sure that you have media folder selected in Site Item's `Sitemap media items` field -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is not working on our local as well. It is working on <SitecoreCMDoamin>/sitemap.xml but not working on localhost:3000/sitemap.xml.

We are using rest API layout service.

Comment: I have not used REST Api but I just see fetchers for GraphQl and Disconnected mode. So I am not very sure that it will work OOTB. Btw are you using Experience Edge ? If yes, I am adding some information in answer, do check if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `/sitecore/content/Tenat/Site/Settings` --> In this set the **sitemap mode** field to **store in the file**, similarly, navigate to  `/sitecore/content/Tenat/Site/Settings/Sitemap` and set the **cache type** field to **store in the file**.

After setting the field values publish your site and this should work.

Note: After publishing the site the `sitemap.xml` gets map to sitemap media item in your site (click on site to check) if it is not mapped you won't be able to see the sitemap in `localhost/Vercel`
[image: Settings/Sitemap]

[image: Settings]